# Calculate percentage SQL statement in with data from the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I'm trying to calculate a percentage. The calculation formula should be as following:

> %=(Totale time AAN / (Totale time AAN + totale time UIT))*100

Table looks like this:

```
+------------+-------------+
| DATA_SOORT | DATA_WAARDE |
+------------+-------------+
| TEMP       |          22 |
| AAN        |       14200 |
| UIT        |       10200 |
| HUM        |          44 |
| AAN        |       10000 |
| UIT        |       13000 |
| TEMP       |          23 |
+------------+-------------+
```

DATA_WAARDE from AAN and UIT are in miliseconds.

I tried it with:

```
     SELECT sum((((`DATA_WAARDE`/1000) 
     FROM `IOT_DATA` 
     WHERE `DATA_SOORT`="AAN")/sum(`DATA_WAARDE`/1000) 
     FROM `IOT_DATA` 
     WHERE (`DATA_SOORT`="UIT" OR `DATA_SOORT`="AAN"))*100)
```

The expected result should out of the table above should be 51,05%.

Comment: Wow that's pretty far away from a valid sql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `case when`, the SQL as below:

```
select * from iot_data;
 data_soort | data_waarde 
------------+-------------
 TEMP       |          22
 AAN        |       14200
 UIT        |       10200
 HUM        |          44
 AAN        |       10000
 UIT        |       13000
(6 rows)

 select
     concat(round(sum(case when data_soort='AAN' then data_waarde else null end)*100.0/sum(case when data_soort in ('AAN','UIT') then data_waarde else null end),2),'%') as percent
 from
     iot_data;
+---------+
| percent |
+---------+
| 51.05%  |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: @P.Salmon Yep, changed my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select `DATA_WAARDE`*100/SUM(`DATA_WAARDE`) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) from `IOT_DATA` WHERE (`DATA_SOORT`="UIT" OR `DATA_SOORT`="AAN")
```

you can also encapsulate it into another query that returns just AAN

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(DATA_SOORT='AAN', `DATA_WAARDE`, NULL))
/ SUM(`DATA_WAARDE`) * 100
FROM `IOT_DATA` 
WHERE `DATA_SOORT` IN ('UIT', 'AAN')
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/620541/4/0)

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this using `avg()`:

```
select avg( data_waarde = 'ANN') * 100 as percent
from iot_data
where data_soort in ('UIT', 'AAN');
```